# Special signs in xml

Tags: xml, sed

After the execution of java code which produces a pseudo-xml, I should convert the signs "&" and "<" in xml-language, i.e. "&" and "<".

My code line looks like:

```
os.system('java -jar de.unihd.dbs.heideltime.standalone.jar ' + file + ' -l german | sed -e "s/&/&amp;/g" | sed -i "{ s/</&lt;/g } /^[\?TDA\/]/!" > ' + taggedname)
```

The first part - change all "&" in "<" - works.
But the part with the "<"-sign does not work yet. This part should change all "<" which are NOT followed by a "?", "T", "D", "A" or "/" to "&alt;".
How can this be done correctly?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please show some of the "raw" xml from the java process.

Comment: I simply have cases like: "should be< done". This "<" should be modified to "&alt;".

Comment: I wonder if your xml file should be using `<![[CDATA` instead of mucking about with sed afterwards

Comment: What about:
sed -e 's/<\\([^?TDA/]\\)/\&lt\1/g'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) instead of [sed](/questions/tagged/sed). It has similar syntax but with look-ahead and look-behind assertions:

```
perl -pe 's{&}{&amp;}g; s{<(?![?TDA/])}{&alt;}g'
```

Comment: YES, this is what I looked for. :) Thanks a lot! Additional question: How can I ignore concrete cases, such as "<b/>" and "<i/>" ?

Comment: I.e. if a "<b/>" or "<i/" occurs, the "<" must not be changed.

Comment: @MarkF6: Try to add them to the negative look-ahead: `(?![?TDA/]|[bi]/>)`